# What does android:required="false" mean WRT to uses-permission?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm integrating an SDK and it requires I put this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />
```

I understand `android:required="false"` on a `uses-feature`, but I can't understand the meaning on a permission. It's not listed in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) as a attribute.

Is it similar to `requires` on a `uses-feature`? Where permissions imply features as listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features), then those features are not required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html), it isn't a valid attribute in a `<uses-permission>` tag. It goes on to say (emphasis mine):

> To control filtering, **always explicitly declare hardware features in  elements**, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a `android:required="false"` attribute to the  declaration.

I would suggest your SDK documentation might be wrong, and you should include a `<uses-feature>` tag for any implied features.

Comment: Yeah I think is wrong too, I will tell them and see what they say

Answer (score 5):

`uses-permission` just tells the users that the app will use some feature but it's not mandatory that the device includes it in order to properly work.

`android-required` means that the feature is mandatory, and the app won't be visible for devices that don't implement it.

For instance.-

implies that the application uses camera features. If the camera is a must feature for your app, setting `android:required="true"` will prevent it from being downloaded to devices that have no camera.

**EDIT**

Actually, I was thinking in `uses-feature` tags. `uses-permission` has no `required` attribute.

Comment: "means that the feature is mandatory" it's a permission not a feature, so does it then refer to the implied features?

Comment: And you are saying that permissions are not mandatory by default. Then I wonder why they tell to to add `android:required="false"` to some of the permissions.

Comment: Mmh you're right, I totally mixed permission with feature. Actually, I guess permission has no attribute android:required attribute.

Answer (score 3):

uses-permission does not use the attribute android:required, but uses-feature does. The ideas are similar, but not identical, which is why it's easy to mix up their attribute requirements.